# Open Real Chrome with Selenium and run script

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation

I'm working a project, and I would like to know/understand how can I open the real chrome with a selenium script in python, and run multiple instances.

Comment: you should search for tutorials first

Comment: Already do, I know how to use the remot port, to manually open the real chrome and execute the script, but it's not automatic

Comment: can you then rephrase your question to be more specific ? e.g. what you want to achieve, what you have tried so far, what failed.

Comment: So, I have a script to fill a form on a specific page, but the website detects when it's running and open with selenium (cookies etc) so, my solution is to open the real chrome manually with a specific port and go to the website manually and execute the selenium python script to fill the informations.
Now what I want to do is to : First step, Open real chrome automatically (without cmd) and fill the informations
and in the second time, do the first step but with multiple instances

Comment: Can you share your code and the website you want to test?